# LVM Limitation in any Linux/Unix

Tags: centos, unix, redhat, solaris, lvm

What is LVM limitation (space in GB/TB/PB/EB) in any Linux/Unix?

Comment: Actually asking a question makes your question a lot easier to answer.

Answer (score 4):

That's rather kernel-dependent, but for 32bit 2.6 Linux kernels it's 16TB and 64bit Linux kernels it's 8 Exabytes.